# How to delete multiple rows in for wxDataviewCtrl and wxDataViewVirtualListModel

Tags: wxwidgets

I am using the wxDataviewCtrl and wxDataViewVirtualListModel to show the a long list of data, the wxDataViewVirtualListModel has 3 wxArrayString to store the data.

Currently when I want to delete a row, I will delete the data in 3 wxArrayString and call RowDelete(row) to notify the wxDataViewCtrl.

However, when I want to delete hundreds of rows I need to use a loop to delete them which is very slow.

How can I delete multiple rows faster?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to dig up an old thread, but this pops to the top of the search, and I may have a solution that will help.  The wxDataView example doesn't exactly show how to clear the entire list.  Here is how I did it, and it seems very fast:

In your derived wxDataViewVirtualListModel class, add a function to clear all the column data out of your model.  Like this:

```
void Clear(){
m_myDescriptionColValues.clear();
m_myNumberColValues.clear();
m_myFooColValues.clear();
Reset(0); // This is like DeleteRows(), but better.
}
```

In the wxDataView sample, this would go in the MyListModel class.  Call this function when you want to clear out the model and repopulate the control with fresh data.  It's really fast in my program with several hundred items.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you should use a single `RowsDeleted()` call instead of multiple `RowDeleted()`. You could also use a more efficient representation than 3 parallel arrays, although I seriously doubt it's the bottleneck for just a few hundreds of rows -- but as usual, you need to profile to find out whether this is really [not] the case.